# Laravel datatable service using with relationship different name

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, datatables, laravel-datatables

I tried using 2 words method relationship. How i can implement the relationship in datatable service using `->with`?
In the `query` method looks like this :

```
public function query(Pihak $model)
    {
        $model = Pihak::query()
            ->with(['categoryStatus'])
            ->where('client_id', $this->clientid);
        return $this->applyScopes($model);
    }
```

Which is has different name with database table (database table name for `categoryStatus` is `master_category_status`) and then i called it in column like this :

```
Column::make('categoryStatus')->data('categoryStatus.name')
->name('categoryStatus.name')
```

Here is it Pihak model

```
class Pihak extends Model
{

    public $table = 'pihaks';
public function categoryStatus()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\MasterCategoryStatus::class, 'category_status_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I got an error `Requested unknown parameter 'categoryStatus.name'`

Comment: Can you add the code for your `Pihak` model please?

Comment: Okay, i've add it in my question @Unflux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. I don't know why it should be snake case method but i'm trying using the method with snake case method (`category_status`) and it works